# Smart Target 2011 SP1 intermittent publishing problem

Tags: 2011, publishing, smarttarget

Publishing SmartTarget promotions in one environment is throwing intermittent errors.  Eventually when you publish the same item enough times, the item will actually publish.  I'm at a lost as to why this would happen.  The deployers are identical for both environments.    Both environments are Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 with SmartTarget 2011 SP2.  The CM does have ST installed on it.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

> 2014-03-12 11:44:32,155 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-10775-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: SmartTarget node not found in the componentpresentations.xml rendering metadata. Please make sure the SmartTarget publisher extension is correctly installed.
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.PublishTransaction.PublishTransaction.validateComponentPresentation(PublishTransaction.java:169) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.PublishTransaction.PublishTransaction.buildComponentPresentations(PublishTransaction.java:71) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.PublishTransaction.PublishTransaction.(PublishTransaction.java:42) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule.process(FredhopperDeployerModule.java:52) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:74) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:73) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]

Answer (score 1):

You state that it the problem intermittent and only in one of your environments. The error also specifically asks, "`Please make sure the SmartTarget publisher extension is correctly installed`".

Do you have more than one publisher service working in that environment and if so, can you verify that they ALL have SmartTarget installed?

Comment: Yes both CM servers have the publisher extension installed.  We even shut off publishing on both servers one at a time to see if it was a problem with one of the CMs or the other.  The same intermittent results occurred.  I think our next steps will be to reinstall the extensions.  We also took a copy of the deployer and tested that out in a different environment and it works as expected there.